# Canvas tile based game has a difficult collision bug

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, tiles

I'm a beginner at game development and have been struggling with getting collision done right between an array of tiles and a player rectangle. This game features jumping and gravity. First of all the collision works, but is very clunky. Sometimes when the player ends up on top of a tile and a little to the edge, it will instantly teleport to either the right or left side (depending on what edge/corner) and fall of it. This also happens when colliding with the bottom of the tile; the player will instantly teleport to the side and go up further. From what I understand the tile collision detector confuses the collision with one or the other side because when the player hits the edge of a tile the detector reads it as if it collided with both and decides to place the player elsewhere base on the highest coordinate velocity (aka speedX and speedY). I figured this out by setting speedY = 0 every time it hits the top of a tile, which fixed the issue, but another one came out of it. Now, if the player is on top of a tile and then falls of and shortly strafe back, it doesn't collide with the tile's side, but it rather quickly goes back on top of it again.

I just need some tips on how i should resolve this, because everything I try leads to another problem. I've heard this is a common bug among developing 2D tile based games.

Here is a jsfiddle with the code in action: https://jsfiddle.net/8121u356/

And here is the display of my entire code:

```
function startGame() { //Starts after all assets have finished loading into the browser
    gameArea.start();
    actor = new player(32, 32, "green", 32, 32);
}

var mapArray = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

];

function TileCollisionManager() {
    let tileSize = 32;
    let baseCol = Math.floor(actor.x / tileSize);
    let baseRow = Math.floor(actor.y / tileSize);
    let colOverlap = actor.x % tileSize;
    let rowOverlap = actor.y % tileSize;

    if (actor.speedX > 0) { //horizontal collision detection
        if ((mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)) {
            actor.x = baseCol * tileSize;
        }
    }

    if (actor.speedX < 0) {
        if ((!mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && rowOverlap)) {
            actor.x = (baseCol + 1) * tileSize;
        }
    }



    if (actor.speedY > 0) { //vertical collision detection
        if ((mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) || //Collision with the top of a tile
            (mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && !mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && colOverlap)) {
            actor.y = ((baseRow) * tileSize);
            actor.jumping = false;
            actor.speedY = 0;
        }
    }

    if (actor.speedY < 0) { //Collision with the bottom of a tile
        if ((!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol]) ||
            (!mapArray[baseRow + 1][baseCol + 1] && mapArray[baseRow][baseCol + 1] && colOverlap)) {
            actor.y = (baseRow + 1) * tileSize;
        }
    }
}

var levelRows = 20;
var levelCols = 20;
var gameArea = {
    canvas : document.getElementById('canvas'),

    start : function() {
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
        window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        });

        window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
            gameArea.keys = (gameArea.keys || []);
            gameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
        })
    },

    clear : function(){
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    render : function() {
        context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        var tileSize = 32;
        for(i=0;i<levelRows;i++){
            for(j=0;j<levelCols;j++){
                if(mapArray[i][j]==1){
                    context.fillStyle = "gray";
                    context.fillRect(j*tileSize,i*tileSize,tileSize,tileSize);
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function updateGameArea() { //loop function
    gameArea.clear();
    gameArea.render();
    actor.update();
    actor.newPos();
    actor.speedX = 0;
    actor.speedY += actor.gravity;

    if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[39]) {
        actor.speedX = 4;
    }
    if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[37]) {
        actor.speedX = -4;
    }
    if (gameArea.keys && gameArea.keys[32]) { //jump
        if (!actor.jumping) {
            actor.jumping = true;
            actor.speedY = -actor.speed * 3;
        }
    }
    TileCollisionManager();
    if (!TileCollisionManager) {
        actor.speedY += actor.gravity;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(updateGameArea);
}

function player (width, height, color, x, y) { //player component

    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.speedX=0;
    this.speedY=0;
    this.gravity=0.3;
    this.speed=3;
    this.jumping=false;
    this.color = color;

    this.update = function () {
        ctx = gameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(
            this.x,
            this.y,
            this.width, this.height);

    };
    this.newPos = function () {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;

    };
}
```

Comment: I suggest trying Unity3d game engine. You'll need less time to learn how to use it than the time that you'll spend building a game in JS.

Comment: I understand unity is better for production. But, my intention with this game is to learn from programming it from scratch. Maybe I could read into how the unity code works and take some ideas from it.